# How to make cell in Excel unclickable and unactive even when click?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

First and foremost, I do know on how to protect the Excel files and I also know on how to Locked Or Hidden cell. The unlock cells let user to edit the cell while the lock cells will not let the user edit the cell. Of course, when I do click the Locked Cell, I still can 'click' it but cannot change the value. But, how do I want to make the cell 'unclickable'. This means that, when I do click the cell, the cell will not 'selected' (that have green square)

Answer (score 1):

To protect only certain cells, columns or rows in Excel:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the cells of the sheet
- Right click and choose "Format cells"
- Go to the Protection tab and uncheck "Locked", click OK
- Now select only the cells, columns or rows that you want to protect
- Right click and choose "Format cells" again
- Go to the protection tab and check "Locked", click OK
- Go to Review tab and click Protect Sheet
- Add a password and ensure that "Select locked cells" is unchecked
- Click OK and save the worksheet.

To unprotect, just go to the review tab, click "Unprotect sheet"
and enter the password.

Comment: Do the steps listed on the answer make the cell(s) unclickable as requested by the OP?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Yes, a click on the protected cells does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/590142-is-there-a-way-to-make-cell-unselectable.html), just select another cell when the targeted cell is selected. You will need to use VBA.

1. Press ALT+F11
2. On the left pane, double click on the sheet name
3. Enter the code below. If A3 (targeted cell) is selected, then select A1.

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(True, True) = "$A$3" Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]